# Downloading a CSV file using PHP from an API - with a URL that doesn't end with .csv

Tags: php, csv, curl, download, file-put-contents

I have been trying to download a file from an API in 2 different way without any success: `https://example.com/export/banana/by_date/v4?api_token=666&from=$today&to=$today`

*Notice the file doesn't end with `.csv`, it just pop out the download
   file for the file.

The file that gets downloaded is a .CSV file.

I tried using CURL:

```
// Date looks like this: 2016-01-31     
$today = date("Y-m-d");

    $output_filename = "test.csv";

    $host = "https://example.com/export/banana/by_date/v4?api_token=666&from=$today&to=$today";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.example.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($result); // prints the contents of the collected file before writing..


    // the following lines write the contents to a file in the same directory (provided permissions etc)
    $fp = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fclose($fp);
```

- With this code I got a black test.csv file.
- I don't get anything printed on the screen after running the function (`print_r($result)`)

and I tried using `file_put_contents` function:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
echo $today;
file_put_contents("", fopen("https://example.com/export/banana/by_date/v4?api_token=666&from=$today&to=$today", 'r'));
// I TRIED THIS ONE TOO: 
// file_put_contents("temp.csv", "https://example.com/export/banana/by_date/v4?api_token=666&from=$today&to=$today");
```

*I get a CSV file with the URL inside it on the first row (`https://example.com/export/banana/by_date/v4?api_token=666&from=2016-01-31&to=2016-01-31`).

Can someone help me by telling me if I am doing this right? (since this isn't a direct link to a file maybe I'm working the wrong way). 
And what is the right way doing this.

Comment: so `print_r($results)` shows the content, but nothing shows up in the saved file?

Comment: Does the `print_r` work properly? If so, it's a PHP issue; otherwise, it's a CURL issue.

Comment: @RST yes. I get an empty CSV.

Comment: @BradzTech actually no, I don't get anything printed on the screen after running the function.

Comment: Try `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` where you have the `print_r`.

Comment: `string '' (length=0)` @BradzTech

Comment: Your answer to my question should have been " No, `print_r()` doesn't show anything either." By that it would have more obvious your empty file is not the problem, but not retrieving data from the url is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target url is `https` so perhaps you need to add certain ssl specific options

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( '/path/to/cacert.pem' ) );
```

another common cause of curl requests failing is the lack of a useragent string.

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'my useragent string' );
```

You can set similar options when using `file_get_contents` by setting options for the `$context`

Based on your last comment, add:

```
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is: 
`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( '/path/to/cacert.pem' ) );`

Comment: I added: `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );` and `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );` and I get: 
and I get `The resource was found at https://example.com/export/banana/by_date/v4?api_token=666&from=$today&to=$today_KJAGS; you should be redirected automatically.`
the `_KJAGS` in the end of the URL is added, and changes the string every time I refresh the page.

Comment: you can download `cacert.pem` from the interwebs - easy to find. It is a collection of certificates for validation tasks. The `realpath()` - replace the path with the actual path the the file on your system if you intend to use it

Comment: I added this after `print_r($result);`: 

`$match = ''; preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $result, $match); print_r($match[0][0]); file_put_contents($match[0][0]);`

Comment: and I got the right output. 

I noticed that the api URL generates a new URL so I just download it using `file_put_contents`.

Comment: Tnx mate! 
You helped me figure this out :) !

Answer (score 0):

This is well known (for me) problem with accesing https resources with cURL from php - it can't verify certificate in default configuration. So easiest thing to get this script works, you should add two additional lines for curl_config:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$output_filename = "test.csv";

$host = "https://example.com/export/banana/by_date/v4?api_token=666&from=$today&to=$today";
$ch = curl_init();
$curl_config = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $host,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => false,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => "https://www.example.com",
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0, //do not verify that host matches one in certifica
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0, //do not verify certificate's meta
];

curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_config); //apply config

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (empty($result)){
    echo  curl_error($ch); //show possible error if answer if empty and exit script
    exit;
}

curl_close($ch);

print_r($result); // prints the contents of the collected file before writing..

// the following lines write the contents to a file in the same directory (provided permissions etc)
file_put_contents($output_filename, $result);
```

Comment: the two additional lines are `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` ? 
Am I right?

Comment: Yes. I've corrected answer adding line where config is applied.